# Issue in IE11 want flex-content-item to occupy full width same as table

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, dom-events

Issue in IE11; 
I want flex-content-item to occupy width same as table with scroll bar.

I tried using some flex concept but did not work.

To understand where is flex-content-item I have added a red border.

Now this border is available till 100%, I want it to wrap the entire table. This is working in Chrome but not in IE11.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .flex-parent{
            min-width: 0;
            max-width: none;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column wrap;
        }
        .flex-content-item{
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: flex-start;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            display: flex;
            margin: 0px 0px 14.0px 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            min-height: 42.0px;
            min-width: 0;
            width: auto;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-content-item">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th> 
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson</td>
                <td>94</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the red border to wrap the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

To the flex-parent container, try to use "display: inline-flex", instead of using "display:flex", code as below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .flex-parent {
        min-width: 0;
        max-width: none;
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
    }

    .flex-content-item {
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0px 0px 14.0px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        min-height: 42.0px;
        min-width: 0;
        width: auto;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

Then, the result in IE browser like this:

[image]